# Pandas: Calculate running difference between prior record between date-time stamps

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data set where I'm tracking user interactions. If the same user has two interactions in the same half-hour period, I want to count that as a single interaction, so I need to calc the difference in time between records in a dataframe

I'm doing this in Pandas. Assume it's sorted by user_id, then datetime stamp. And it needs to reset when a new ID is encountered so previous ID needs to be stored to compare to current ID. Here's desired output

```
user id       datetime               desired column: minute diff from prior timestamp
1             2020-03-27T12:29:00    NAN
1             2020-03-27T12:31:00    2
1             2020-03-27T14:03:00    92
1             2020-03-27T14:27:00    24
2             2020-03-27T11:29:00    NAN
2             2020-03-27T14:29:00    180
2             2020-03-27T14:54:00    25
2             2020-03-27T18:20:00    216
```

I've tried playing around with Pandas.DataFram.rolling, but I either severely misunderstand its usage (possible!) or it just doesn't have the functionality I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by user column and do a [pandas.Series.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), then get total minute.

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df['output'] = df.groupby('user').datetime.diff().dt.total_seconds().div(60)
```

Output

```
      user            datetime  output
0        1 2020-03-27 12:29:00     NaN
1        1 2020-03-27 12:31:00     2.0
2        1 2020-03-27 14:03:00    92.0
3        1 2020-03-27 14:27:00    24.0
4        2 2020-03-27 11:29:00     NaN
5        2 2020-03-27 14:29:00   180.0
6        2 2020-03-27 14:54:00    25.0
7        2 2020-03-27 18:20:00   206.0
```

Comment: The negative number was because of the switch to a new user id. This would not always be negative though, so I couldn't just replace all < 0 with NaN... I may be able to adapt this approach though, in which case I'll mark as the answer.

Comment: I did not know `user` was a factor. I have updated the answer @Jimthefourth

Comment: fantastic, thanks: as a final note to anyone coming across this, I decided I wanted NaN to default to specific value as I needed to sort out only low values, so I amended the solution to ...dt.total_seconds().div(60).fillna(99999)